# How to POST data using javascript

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

This my JS code:

```
$.when(d1, d2).done(function(v1, v2) {
    var url = v1;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(url);
        }
    };
    xhr.send("deployment_preference_set_fleet_health_attributes_concurrent_hosts_percentage=31");
});
```

After certain processing I will get a URL which will be passed to `v1`.

HTML Content of the corresponding URL

```
<input id="deployment_preference_set_fleet_health_attributes_concurrent_hosts_percentage" max="100" min="0" name="deployment_preference_set[fleet_health_attributes][concurrent_hosts_percentage]" size="3" step="any" type="number" value="30.0" />
% or less of the hosts in the fleet can be deployed to at a time.
```

What I want is to update the field `deployment_preference_set_fleet_health_attributes_concurrent_hosts_percentage` with a particular value.

I have tried using xmlhttprequest but its not working.

Its working upto console.log(v1), but I think xhr.send () is not working since the page I am trying to update is not getting updated

Any suggestion of how update the data on that particular field.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Your syntax is off. I don't see you assigning the result of your ajax request into the DOM input object that you are aiming at.

**Recommendation**

Use Jquery for your AJAX calls. If you use xhr you will need to handle different formats across different browsers and that might be part of your issue.

**Format**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**Example**

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( responseData ) {
  $( "#deployment_preference_set_fleet_health_attributes_concurrent_hosts_percentage" ).val( responseData );
});
```

Reference -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the Content-Type header. When using the POST method, you need to set the Content-Type header (via the `setRequestHeader` method of the `XMLHttpRequest` object) or the data cannot be retrieved from the request body on the other end.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //make xhr
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded');// <-- do this!

xhr.send('my_data=hi&your_data=no');
```

In your case, all you need to do is define the Content-Type header at some point before doing `xhr.send()`.